# Bootstrap 3 tabs: dropdown menus not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is portion of the html code for Bootstrap tab:

```
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse1">
              <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav">-->
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-toggle="collapse-nav" data-target="#more-menu-allowed">


              <li class="dropdown">
                <a id="dropdownuser" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" ><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-cogwheel text-danger"></span> <%=t('Time Sheets') %> <b class="caret" id="caret_medium"></b></a>
                <ul id="namelist" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"></ul>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><%= link_to "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-list'></i> #{I18n.t('List')}".html_safe, SUBURI + "/view_handler?index=1&url=#{ pay_timex.time_sheets_path}" if has_action_right?('index', 'pay_timex/time_sheets') %></li>
                  <li><%= link_to "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i> #{I18n.t('New')}".html_safe, SUBURI + "/view_handler?index=1&url=#{ pay_timex.new_time_sheet_path}" if has_action_right?('new', 'pay_timex/time_sheets') %></li>
                  <li><%= link_to "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></i> #{I18n.t('Search')}".html_safe, SUBURI + "/view_handler?index=1&url=#{ pay_timex.search_time_sheets_path}" if has_action_right?('search', 'pay_timex/time_sheets') %></li>                
                </ul>
              </li>
            ......
```

The tab shows fine. However the dropdown menu is not showing (showing a small overlap) when clicking the tab. What could make the dropdown menu showing again?

### Update

The tab image:

[image]

Comment: I can see 2 `<ul>` under the `<li>` dropdown. Try removing the first one maybe? Also, would be better if you can provide a jsfiddle snippet. Thanks!

Comment: `melvindidit` my bad. there is error within the <li> and it is not showing. also I can remove the  double <ul>  without any problem.